# Solve this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am given the following limit to solve, presumably without knowledge of L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{x}{1-\cos x}}\right)^2$$

I tried using trigonometric identities (namely Pythagorean) to solve it, but with no luck.

Comment: Figure out $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}$ and go from there.

Comment: Where you mistaking $(1-cos)^2$ with $1-cos^2(x)$?

Comment: $1-\cos x=2\sin^2 \frac x2$. Try this, the sequence should be divergent i.e. $\lim \dots =\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{x}{1-\cos x}}\right)^2=$

$\displaystyle = \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{x}{2\sin^2 \frac x2}}\right)^2=$

$\displaystyle = \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin^2 \frac x2}}\right)^2=$

$\displaystyle = \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac x2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \frac x2}\right)^2=$

$\displaystyle =\left(1\cdot \frac{1}{0} \right)^2=$

$=\infty$

Comment: I see you used the identity $\cos{2x}=1-\sin^{2}{x}$. Did you use the product rule for limits between your third and fourth step?

Comment: @Steve yes, I used $ sin^2x = sinx \cdot sinx $ 
and $ \frac{sinx }{x} \rightarrow 1$ when$ x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Sorry, I meant in between your fourth and fifth step. You seem to be finding the limit of the products even though the expression is raised to the second power, which I didn't think was possible.

Comment: @Steve yes, you can think as $\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac x2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \frac x2} \cdot \frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac x2}  \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \frac x2}=1\cdot \frac{1}{0}\cdot1\cdot \frac{1}{0} = 1 \cdot \infty \cdot 1 \cdot \infty = \infty$

Comment: But now that the expression is written that way, $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ sin\frac { x }{ 2 }  }  }$ is undefined since $\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 0 }^{ - } }{ \frac { 1 }{ sin\frac { x }{ 2 }  }  } =-\infty$ and $\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 0 }^{ + } }{ \frac { 1 }{ sin\frac { x }{ 2 }  }  } =\infty$

Comment: yes you have right, this not work as I told in my last comment... but I'm pretty sure my solution is correct because the  expression is raised to the second power

Comment: You are right since $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( \frac { 1 }{ sin\frac { x }{ 2 }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }=\infty$, I'm just hung up on the fact that the product rule CAN be expression raised to the second power. As soon as you actually expand the expression, the solution falls apart.

Comment: but if you write like this $\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac x2}} \right)^2 \cdot \left({\frac{ 1}{\sin \frac x2}} \right)^2= \lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{ \frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac x2}} \right)^2 \cdot {\frac{ 1}{\left(\sin \frac x2\right)^2}} $ ?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac x{1-\cos x}=\frac x{1-\cos x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{x(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2x}$$